# Are vertices in a clockwise order?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, geometry

Your program must accept as input six numbers, which describe a triangle - for example, the inputs 80, 23, 45, 1, 76, -2 describe a triangle with vertices (80, 23), (45, 1), and (76, -2). The input must be given as six plain real numbers or as a list of six real numbers, in the order given in the example. Your task is to figure out whether the triangle's vertices are given in clockwise order. Assume that the input vertices are not all in one line. In this case, the vertices are not in clockwise order because the second vertex is to the bottom-left of the first.

This is code-golf, meaning the submission with the shortest number of bytes wins. Good luck!

Comment: What I/O formats can we use? Are tuples/arrays of numbers fine? What about complex numbers?

Comment: Tuples/arrays are fine. No complex numbers.

Comment: Can we take the points as a list of three pairs? Or, can we take the points as two lists of length three, being the X and Y coordinate lists?

Comment: No, the parameters / list must be in the order above.

Comment: I've changed "characters" to "bytes" - the key distinction is that some languages can use multi-byte characters to exploit this wording, which did occur in the past before bytes became the standard. Feel free to revert this edit if you intend to use characters for scoring, but the [tag:code-golf] tag measures by bytes since it's usually a more accurate scoring method.

Comment: Can you add some test cases?

Comment: I have proposed an edit to include a worked example. Hopefully this could extend to test cases.

Comment: For future reference, we strongly recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140) to get feedback on your challenges before you post them to the main site.

Comment: Please [avoid cumbersome I/O formats](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/43319).

Comment: @Adám Would upvote your comment but accidently hit upvote twice. Don't know why ppl get so caught-up on minor parts of their posts. This is code-golf, let people answer creatively.

Comment: @Noodle9 Often because they actually need this for some homework or test…

Comment: @Adám That's truly shameful behaviour. They have the whole internet to explore and learn from, yet resort to underhanded ways of getting other ppl to do the work for them.

Answer (score 14):

## JavaScript (ES6), 38 bytes

Returns a Boolean value (*true* for clockwise).

```javascript
(a,b,c,d,e,f)=>a*d+b*e+c*f<b*c+a*f+d*e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLDsIwDAXAq3iZOK8VFPpZUO7iODYCVQ2iiOuHmZf85NDP8/3t9lqs@dqCIENRYPC43oVLymxJ2W@ZNQl7KmxN637UzfqtPoKH5QQaLqDrCDqD5gnUDTG2Pw)

$$D=\begin{vmatrix}
a&b&1\\
c&d&1\\
e&f&1
\end{vmatrix}=(ad-bc)-(af-be)+(cf-de)$$

$$D<0\iff ad+be+cf<bc+af+de$$

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
s2;€1ÆḊṠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/YyPpR0xrDw20Pd3Q93Lng////FgY6CkbGOgompjoKhjoK5mY6CrpGAA)

-2 bytes thanks to Bubbler by transposing the matrix from ngn's formula which saves bytes on padding with 1s, since determinant is invariant over transposition.

Outputs `-1` for clockwise and `1` for counterclockwise. Stole ngn's formula [from chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58180608).

```
s2;€1ÆḊṠ   Main Link; [x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2]
s2         Slice into chunks of size 2; [[x0, y0], [x1, y1], [x2, y2]]
  ;        Append...
   €       to each chunk...
    1      1; [[x0, y0, 1], [x1, y1, 1], [x2, y2, 1]]
     ÆḊ    Determinant
       Ṡ   Sign
```

Comment: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9qZWxsef//czIgMeG5reKxrsOG4biK4bmg////ODAsIDIzLCA0NSwgMSwgNzYsIC0y)

Comment: @Bubbler Oh, nice. And very nice observation about the transpose being unnecessary; thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>62</s> <s>44</s> 36 bytes

*Edit: Realized that I'd ridiculously over-engineered my first version after looking at [Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226564/95126) which uses the same approach.  Upvote that!*

*Edit 2: And then I looked [hyper-neutrino's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226557/95126) (upvote that one, too!) realized that that strategy would be shorter anyway.*

```r
function(p)det(rbind(matrix(p,2),1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfmFeSmZyTn5xdnlmcavs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQDMltUSjKCkzL0UjN7GkKLNCo0DHSFPHUFMTVY9GsoaFgY6CkbGOgompjoKhjoK5mY6CrpGmpoKyAopKLlz6IBqg@sH64Kr@AwA)

Outputs a positive value for anticlockwise, and a negative value for clockwise.  Add 2 bytes (`>0`) ([like this](https://tio.run/##K/qfmFeSmZyTn5xdnlmcavs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQDMltUSjKCkzL0UjN7GkKLNCo0DHSFPHUFPTzgBVl0ayhoWBjoKRsY6CiamOgqGOgrmZjoKukaamgrICikouXPogGqD6wfrgqv4DAA)) if you prefer to have a `TRUE`/`FALSE` output.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>24</sup> 16 bytes

```
0>1-/ .*@,.3 2$]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DewMdfUV9LQcdPSMFYxUYv9rcqUmZ@QrqLsl5hRXqkM4aQoWBgpGxgompgqGCuZmCvFGUEUhRaUlGeiqwAogamESYA6yrMJ/AA)

<sup>-8 thanks to Bubbler for pointing out I could take a single determinant of a 3x3 to implement the shoelace formula</sup>

Takes input as a single list.

Looks like hyper-neutrino beat me to the idea, which is just to use the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) and then check if the answer is negative.

Since the shoelace formula expects the coordinates in counter-clockwise order, it will be negative only when they're in clockwise order.

### how

Consider the input:

```
80 23 45 1 76 _2
```

- `3 2$]` Shape into matrix:

  ```
  80 23
  45  1
  76 _2
  ```
- `1...,.` Zip with 1:

  ```
  1 80 23
  1 45  1
  1 76 _2
  ```
- `-/ .*` Determinant:

  ```
  787
  ```
- `0>` Is it negative?

  ```
  0
  ```

Comment: OP answered "no" to "Can we take the points as a list of three pairs?". And if you were to use determinant built-in, directly using it on 3x3 is [shorter](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DewMdfUV9LQcdPSMFYxUYv9rcqUmZ@QrpClYGCgYGSuYmCoYKpibKcQboYqDhSCyMAkwB1lW4T8A) anyway.

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.matrices.laplace`, 44 bytes

```
[ 2 group [ 1 suffix ] map determinant sgn ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYw7DgIhFEV7V3E3IFH8RhdgbGyM1WQKgg8kMgw@INEY145Em1Pcm3OM0nnkejkfT4cdLI8lumCR6FEoaEq4EwfyGFS@/SAa2LVHeBW90oTIlPMrsgsZ@8kb2xnkAssV5tisMZX41A7y30bX1lSMcU/0rRdxpUw8uKCanWxAX7XyHqJ@AQ)

Port of @hyper-neutrino's [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226557/97916).

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB/Octave, 33 bytes

```matlab
@(A)det([reshape(A,2,3);1,1,1])<0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQcNRMyW1RCO6KLU4I7EgVcNRx0jHWNPaUAcIYzVtDP4n5hVrRFsY6CgYGesomJjqKBjqKJib6SjoGsVq/gcA)
Anonymous function. Takes as input list of points (so a vector in MATLAB's nomenclature). It reshapes it into 2x3 array, adds ones and calculates the determinant.
The reshaped  array with ones looks like so:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
A(1) & A(3) & A(5) \\
A(2) & A(4) & A(6) \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 28 bytes

```
≔⪪Ａ²θ›⁰ΣＥθ×§ι⁰ΣＥ³×⊖λ§§θ⁺κ⊖λ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7LCsIwEEX3fkWWE5iC1id0VRCkC6FQd6WL0A4aTGObpOLfx9kE8cIwi3O43P6hXP9SJsbSe3230ExGB6jstASQKHK@WRar2mkb4OJIBXKwRtEsI1zVBDOKmx7JQxkqO9AHNIq1/PFt4mfqHY1kAw1gWEh@@lxUm8XDE8W/KlneyJQixrY98YCcm3d7RiiOBxRZ3nUxe5sv) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for clockwise, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
≔⪪Ａ²θ
```

Split the input into three pairs of coordinates.

```
›⁰ΣＥθ×§ι⁰ΣＥ³×⊖λ§§θ⁺κ⊖λ¹
```

Multiply each coordinate by each cyclically adjacent coordinate and its adjacency, i.e.
$$ x_0 (y_{0+1} + 0y_{0+0} - y_{0-1}) + x_1 (y_{1+1} + 0y_{1+0} - y_{1-1}) + x_2(y_{2+1} + 0y_{2+0} - y_{2-1}) $$
and compare the sum to zero to see whether the vertices are clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 42 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,c,d,e,f:a*d+b*e+c*f<b*c+a*f+d*e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFJCoAwDAXQq2Sp6Re0jojexE06BAUnxI2nr@/d37tep006L2mXwwUhgYNHQISOwsE4jsazTo69EVYTOKb72c4302woQbYGNS2oAvUdqLB5nn4)

Port of Arnuald's JS answer. But unfortunately using dot product is longer, because `@` operator requires numpy.